# Emision light - problem with burning of?

Tags: rendering, texturing

Hi i render this image in 300 sample and use denosing, in my scene i use emision ligt in my lamp and normal spot loght. I have problem with this :

[image]

in my scene look like this :

[image]

Comment: Seems like artifacts from Denoising. Picture is to small to be sure.

Comment: When i render at close range is look ok ;/

Comment: Maybe try to change denoising settings. I can't tell you how though without your blend file.